# How could I use i18n in action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Suppose I record user's preference lang in User model.

`User.lang = :en, :jp, ...`

How could I send the email with 18n suppose I can get the user information in the mailer ?

I invoke the following mailer in rake task

```
class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def notify_user(user, queues)
    @user, @queues = user, queues
    mail(to: [@user.email],
         from: "samplegmail.com",
         subject: "~~~",
         content_type:  "text/html"
    )
  end
```

Comment: How do you generate your mails?

Comment: @Goot I deliver the mails in rake task

Answer (score 1):

you can temporarily set a locale using `I18n.with_locale`, so just create the mail in a block passed to `with_locale`.

```
I18n.with_locale(@user.lang) do
  mail(to: [@user.email],
     from: "samplegmail.com",
     subject: "~~~",
     content_type:  "text/html"
  )
end
```

Comment: there should be a better way to do this today, no?